# Mongodb aggregate - using $addFields inside a nested array to get true/ false

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've been trying to get data back with an additional field inside a nested array using `$addFields`.

The data is:

```
{
  "show_id": 1,
  "ext1_id": 126790,
  "ext2_id": 44275,
  "show_title": "Some Big title name",
  "poster_url": "https://cdn.something.com/media/cover/o65bBCMVI.jpg",
  "description": "show description",
  "year": 2021,
  "episodes": [
    {
      "episode_title": "episode title 1",
      "episode_number": "01",
      "version": null,
      "file_id": "BAACAgUAAx0EYN2eLQADKWGOO8WclqGSBG6Kdy0DkRTAbLgGAALMAgACvj7BVnkS-frrNBz8HgQ",
      "unique_id": "AgADzAIAAr4-wVY",
      "message_id": 41,
      "added_by": "bot",
      "watched_by": [919205468, 1778357657],
      "timestamp": "2021-11-12T15:32:46.172302"
    },
    {
      "episode_title": "Episode title 2",
      "episode_number": "02",
      "version": null,
      "file_id": "BAACAgUAAx0EYN2eLQADKmGOO9QAAZCDz6lonoW1R5zPUM9sVAACOAQAApgFAVdhA3c9xoF0oB4E",
      "unique_id": "AgADOAQAApgFAVc",
      "message_id": 42,
      "added_by": "bot",
      "watched_by": [919205468],
      "timestamp": "2021-11-12T15:33:01.053049"
    },
    {
      "episode_title": "episode title 3",
      "episode_number": "03",
      "version": null,
      "file_id": "BAACAgUAAx0EYN2eLQADK2GOO9zX4pgK7d1ERd5BeQkvvobSAAKaBAAC2tNJVwYVsJ_OGprTHgQ",
      "unique_id": "AgADmgQAAtrTSVc",
      "message_id": 43,
      "added_by": "bot",
      "watched_by": [919205468],
      "timestamp": "2021-11-12T15:33:08.862887"
    }
  ],
  "alt_titles": ["alt title", "ALT TITLE", "Alt-Title"],
  "is_airing": true,
  "added_by": "bot",
  "timestamp": "2021-11-12T15:32:45.298797"
}
```

So basically, what I was trying was to add a field `user_watched` inside the `episodes` list so that it'll just return True / False by checking if the `user_id` is present in the `watched_by` list which is again inside the `episodes` list.

I also didn't want the `watched_by` to be retured in the result.

I expected something like this:

```
{
  "show_id": 1,
  "ext1_id": 126790,
  "ext2_id": 44275,
  "show_title": "Some Big title name",
  "poster_url": "https://cdn.something.com/media/cover/o65bBCMVI.jpg",
  "description": "show description",
  "year": 2021,
  "episodes": [
    {
      "episode_title": "episode title 1",
      "episode_number": "01",
      "version": null,
      "file_id": "BAACAgUAAx0EYN2eLQADKWGOO8WclqGSBG6Kdy0DkRTAbLgGAALMAgACvj7BVnkS-frrNBz8HgQ",
      "unique_id": "AgADzAIAAr4-wVY",
      "message_id": 41,
      "added_by": "bot",
      "user_watched": true,
      "timestamp": "2021-11-12T15:32:46.172302"
    },
    {
      "episode_title": "Episode title 2",
      "episode_number": "02",
      "version": null,
      "file_id": "BAACAgUAAx0EYN2eLQADKmGOO9QAAZCDz6lonoW1R5zPUM9sVAACOAQAApgFAVdhA3c9xoF0oB4E",
      "unique_id": "AgADOAQAApgFAVc",
      "message_id": 42,
      "added_by": "bot",
      "user_watched": true,
      "timestamp": "2021-11-12T15:33:01.053049"
    },
    {
      "episode_title": "episode title 3",
      "episode_number": "03",
      "version": null,
      "file_id": "BAACAgUAAx0EYN2eLQADK2GOO9zX4pgK7d1ERd5BeQkvvobSAAKaBAAC2tNJVwYVsJ_OGprTHgQ",
      "unique_id": "AgADmgQAAtrTSVc",
      "message_id": 43,
      "added_by": "bot",
      "user_watched": true,
      "timestamp": "2021-11-12T15:33:08.862887"
    }
  ],
  "alt_titles": ["alt title", "ALT TITLE", "Alt-Title"],
  "is_airing": true,
  "added_by": "bot",
  "timestamp": "2021-11-12T15:32:45.298797"
}
```

I tried this following code in pymongo:

```
db.data_col.aggregate([        
    {'$sort'     : { 'timestamp' : -1 } },
    {'$facet'    : {
        "metadata": [ { "$count": "total" } ],
        "data": [ 
            {'$addFields': {
                    'episodes.user_watched': 
                        {'$cond': [
                            {
                                '$in': [
                                    919209968,
                                    "$episodes.watched_by"
                                ]
                            },
                            True,
                            False
                        ]
                    }
                }},
            
            { "$skip": offset }, { "$limit": limit },
            { '$project' : {"episodes.watched_by":0} } ,
        ]
    }}
])
```

but I got every `user_watched` fields False even if the `user_id` is present among the `watched_by` list.
and the [returned data](https://yaso.su/D7kp8HdX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- map on episodes, check if the `user(1778357657)` in in the `watched_by` array and add the field true/false
- removed the field watched_by

*your query looks different i guess you do more things, but this produces the expected output

*your code didn't work because "$episodes.watched_by", is an array that contains all the watched_by arrays, with `$map` each array is checked separately.

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62327382f7e3c64c6511e13a)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"episodes": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$episodes",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$this",
             {"user_watched": 
               {"$in": [1778357657, "$$this.watched_by"]}}]}}}}},
 {"$set": {"episodes.watched_by": "$$REMOVE"}}])
```